# list generator/comprehension for reading from file and putting in list

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator

Let's say I start off by making a class, with the variable `self.memory = [None] * 10000`.
Now I have a file structured like so:

```
1 1231
2 1231
3 asdma
4 landsl
```

I want to make a generator statement that will read each line of the file and put it in the self.memory variable at its specified index (the left number).
Is such a statement possible?

EDIT: adding what I am using currently:

```
def AbsoluteLoader(self, f):                                                                                          
     with open(f, 'r') as assembly:                                                                                    
        for line in assembly:                                                                                         
          c = line.split()                                                                                          
          if int(c[0]) == -1:                                                                                       
            self.pc = long(c[1])                                                                                  
            break                                                                                                 
          try:                                                                                                      
            self.memory[int(c[0])] = long(c[1])                                                                   
          except:                                                                                                   
            print 'invalid'
```

Comment: Why do you think you need a generator statement?

Comment: don't necessarily "need" one, I just think it will be nice.

Comment: Why don't you post your code so far and ask a question about it?

Comment: Generators work while they are being consumed. What would consume this process?

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, fname, lines=10000):
        self.pc = None
        self.memory = mem = [0L] * lines

        with open(fname) as inf:
            for line in inf:
                ndx, num = line.split()
                ndx = int(ndx)
                num = long(num)
                try:
                    mem[ndx] = num
                except IndexError:
                    if ndx == -1:
                        self.pc = num
                        break
                    else:
                        raise ValueError('invalid entry: {}'.format(line.rstrip('\r\n')))
```